# Show/Hide Divs based on Anchor Href attr that matches the Hash in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, hashtag

I have found a lot of info on URL's with Hash, but nothing to solve this.  I have divs that are hidden then shown when you click it's parent.  What I want to add in is if you come in with a #Hash tag that matches the anochor's href attr - trigger it was clicked.

Code I have now:

```
$('.speaker_container').on('click','.speaker_img',function(){ $(this).siblings('.speaker-bios').toggle(150);});


 <section id="speakers">
<div class="speaker_container clearfix">
    <div class="speaker_img">
        <a class="speaker_img" href="#speaker1"><img>Text</a>
    </div>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <p class="clearfix">Text</p>
    <div class="speaker-bios" style="display: none;">
        <p>Hidden text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="speaker_container clearfix">
    <div class="speaker_img">
        <a class="speaker_img" href="#speaker2"><img>Text</a>
    </div>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <p class="clearfix">Text</p>
    <div class="speaker-bios" style="display: none;">
        <p>Hidden text</p>
    </div>
</div>
and so on....
```

`

Comment: Maybe you can provide a jsfiddle to make it easier to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$(function(){
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   if(hash != 'undefined'){
      $('a[href='+hash+']').parents('div.speaker_container').trigger('click');

   }
});
```

Comment: Had to switch out the div.speaker_container to .speaker_img  `$(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash != 'undefined'){
   $('a[href='+hash+']').parents('.speaker_img').trigger('click');
    }
 });`

Answer (score -1):

How about (if JQuery)

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(hash).show();
```

Comment: This will not work, as `hash` begins with `#`. `$(hash)` will try to select an element by id, but it should have selected by href.